# Segregate the column Category wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe need to perform certain operation on it but not able to exact final output as needed.

```
data = {
    "Category": ["900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK"],
    "Size": [1041.4, 1020, 711.2, 660.4, 648.6, 584.2, 562.8, 508, 495.3, 488.95, 381, 431.8, 482.6, 520.7, 533.4, 558.8, 584.2, 609.6, 660.4, 750.062],
    "Count": [6, 1, 10, 10, 10, 23, 22, 1, 6, 3, 7, 2, 5, 8, 9, 22, 23, 10, 10, 6]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Raw data:

[image]

Here for tranform dataframe by adding new column as Total Count where we need to group in every category with the nearest Size value in range of 25
below is the example for it.

[image: ![Operation to perform]

Final output needed where we need to extract the rows from every group if group has multiple row then need to extract only row which has highest value from the size column

[image: Final Output Needed]

Comment: [Don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, [Series.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) can help you determine if the difference in 2 rows is within 25, [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) can help you group the values, [max](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) can give you the maximum value, etc

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Like, to start, do you know how to use `.groupby`? For the "nearest Size value", have you considered using `.diff`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "Category": ["900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "900IG", "165LK",
                 "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK", "165LK"],
    "Size": [1041.4, 1020, 711.2, 660.4, 648.6, 584.2, 562.8, 508, 495.3, 488.95, 381, 431.8, 482.6, 520.7, 533.4,
             558.8, 584.2, 609.6, 660.4, 750.062],
    "Count": [6, 1, 10, 10, 10, 23, 22, 1, 6, 3, 7, 2, 5, 8, 9, 22, 23, 10, 10, 6]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_closest_size_count(x):
    # get df for category wihtout current row
    _df = df[
        (df.index != x.name) &
        (df.Category == x.Category)
    ]

    # calculate all absolute differences
    abs_diffs = abs(_df.Size - x.Size)

    # filter to max diff of 25
    abs_diffs = abs_diffs[abs_diffs <= 25]

    if abs_diffs.empty:
        return 0
     
    # sum of nearest counts  
    # _df.Count[abs_diffs.index].sum()

    # return count where difference is the smallest
    return _df.Count[abs_diffs.idxmin()]


df['TotalCount'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x.Count + get_closest_size_count(x),
    axis=1
)
```